# MiKTeX 2.9, LyX 2.1, BibLaTeX: How do I suppress language after title field in references?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chem

I am using BibLaTeX with LyX and have the following as my TeX file:

```
%% LyX 2.1.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,english]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
%\documentclass{scrbook}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=chem-acs,hyperref=true,babel=hyphen,doi=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

%page header and footer



%Superscripts and brackets in citation footnotes can be obtained by redefining \@makefntext. 

%Citation and "vanilla" footnotes can be printed as separate lists using the manyfoot package.
\usepackage{manyfoot}

% Citation footnotes: use \footnoteA
%\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[roman]
%
%% Vanilla footnotes: use \footnoteB
%\DeclareNewFootnote{B}

% Number of each bibliography entry in brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\makeatletter

\newtoggle{cbx@togcite}

% Citation number superscript in brackets
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}


\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
  citetracker=true,sorting=none,alldates=long,dateabbrev=false,%
  articletitle=true,maxcitenames=1}

% No brackets around the number of each bibliography entry
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\addperiod}

% Suppress article title, doi, url, etc. in citations
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\clearfield{title}}
    {}%
  \clearfield{doi}%
  \clearfield{url}%
  \clearlist{publisher}%
  \clearlist{location}%
  \clearfield{note}}

% Print year instead of date, when available; make use of urldate
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}
\renewbibmacro*{date}{% Based on date bib macro from chem-acs.bbx
  \iffieldundef{year}
    {\ifentrytype{online}
       {\printtext[urldate]{\printurldate}}
       {\printtext[date]{\printdate}}}
    {\printfield[date]{year}}}

% Remove period from titles
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}


%---------------------------------------------------------------
% Essentially verbatim from Joseph Wright
% http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/
\makeatletter

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
      \iffieldundef{postnote}
        {}
        {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{sfcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{sfcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
  {}
  {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
   \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
     \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
  \cbx@citehook%
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}
\let\cbx@citehook=\empty

\makeatother
%---------------------------------------------------------------

\long\def\footnote#1{%
  \begingroup%
  \def\thefootnote{\roman{footnote}}\footnote{#1}%
  \endgroup}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Benfield2003,
  Title                    = {Changing trends in pediatric transplantation: 2001 Annual Report of the North American Pediatric Renal Transplant Cooperative Study.},
  Author                   = {Benfield, Mark R. and McDonald, Ruth A. and Bartosh, Sharon and Ho, P. L. and Harmon, William},
  Journal                  = {Pediatr Transplant},
  Language                 = {eng}, 
  Pages                    = {321--335},
  Volume                   = {7},
  Year                     = {2003},
  Month                    = {Aug},
  Number                   = {4}
}

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}


The first citation.\sfcite{Benfield2003}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

The resultant PDF has reference in footnote as

> 1 Beneld, M. R. et al., eng Pediatr Transplant 2003, 7, 321335.

The title field is suppressed correctly. How do I suppress the eng after title field?

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out.

First, change preamble by adding `\clearlist{language}` this will stop the language field being added in the footnote citation;

```
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\clearfield{title}}
    {}%
  \clearlist{language}%
  \clearfield{doi}%
  \clearfield{url}%
  \clearlist{publisher}%
  \clearlist{location}%
  \clearfield{note}}
```

Next, add `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}` at the end of the preamble after loading the bibresource this will clear the language field from the bibliography.